# Screensaver forces logout?

Tags: 10.10, login-screen, screensaver

I am using the most recent ubuntu desktop edition 10.10.  Everything works fine, except the screensaver.  Instead of going to the screensaver the OS forces a logout and all my apps are shutdown.

Forums suggested checkboxing the 'Lock screen when screensaver active' box, as well as using non gl 3d graphics screensavers, both of which i have tried to no avail.  BTW: I can preview screensavers just fine.

thanks for any recommendations!

Comment: You should file a bug report, that's clearly an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a misbehaving 3D driver library. Besides filing a bug, I would recommend trying to reinstall your video driver via *System / Administration / Additional Drivers* if you are using (or have used) the **fglrx** or **nvidia** drivers.

Comment: I am not using any proprietary drivers on my system.  It is an older desktop and monitor....no frills for sure!